# Unsetting a PHP session with JQuery / AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, session

Button on `index` page:

```
$('#killsession').click(function() {
    $.get('killsession.php');
    alert("OK");
});
```

`killsession.php`:

```
<?php
session_start():
session_destroy();
?>
```

After killing the session with this button, any session-esque related functions on `index` still work (session variables are still set/exist). For example, I have a counting session variable that is incremented when I click a certain button. This counting variable does not lose its spot in counting after killing the session.

Is it possible to kill a session with a JQuery button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the PHP session items are loaded when the page is first loaded. They are still in the page/browser memory as long as the page is open. You need to reload the page after killing the session. You can do this with javascript window.location.href = window.location.href

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#killsession').click(function() {
  $.get('killsession.php', function() {
    alert("the server page executed");
    //Here you may do further things.

    window.location = window.location;
  });
});
```

killsession.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSION = array();

$params = session_get_cookie_params();

setcookie( session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"],
    $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"],
    $params["httponly"]
);

session_destroy();

exit('OK');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are doing other things (like checking session) only inside the call back of ajax function .Whatever inside the callback will be executed after receiving a response from the ajax server page.

```
$('#killsession').click(function() {
    $.get('killsession.php',function(){
       alert("the server page executed");
       //Here you may do further things.

    });

});
```

Comment: Doesn't necessarily address my question, but nonetheless a measure of good coding.+1