# How to check if a session is empty using javascript inside php

Tags: javascript, php, session

Also, how do i unset the session through javascript?

I have made this code with PHP:

```
if(isset($_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION)) {
            unset($_SESSION['Plan1']);
            unset($_SESSION['excel_array']);
            $_POST['excel_name']['Main'] = "Main".date("y_m_d_Hi");
            $_POST['excel_array']['Main']['Plan1'] = array();
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['excel_name']['Main'] = "Main".date("y_m_d_Hi");
            $_SESSION['excel_array']['Main']['Plan1'] = array();
        }
```

So here i check if there is a session. If there is, i unset it and send the $_POST data instead. however, if there isn't one, i create it.

The problem is, i might want to call this on a button click. How would i make a code with the same functionality, but using a javascript function?

Comment: tip: use ajax request

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why javascript, why not a form POST submit?

Comment: Your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839079/unsetting-a-php-session-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: PHP sets a PHP SESSION cookie. Simply delete this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your php in a file on its own, called set_session.php for example:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['Plan1']);
    echo 'unset';
?>
```

Call it in javascript:

```
<script>
function unset() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "set_session.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="unset()">Unset</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```